# UISearchController - search bar should be visible always

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

**Aim:** To have a search bar that is always visible.

1. View controller is embedded in a navigation controller
2. No table view exists
3. When user taps on search bar, search bar needs to animate from its current position to the top of the navigation bar (move **upwards**) like in the **iOS contacts app**.
4. Use `UISearchController`

**What I have done:**

1. I have added the search bar to the view controller's view
2. I am manually presenting the search view controller (code below)

**Problem:**

- I am unable to control the animation, presently the search bar moves **downwards** from top of the screen to the place of the navigation bar.

**Expected behavior:**

- To be able to animate the search bar by moving it **upwards** from the current position to the navigation bar

**Question**

1. Is my approach correct ?
2. How can i animate and move the search bar upwards from the current position ?

**Code:**

```
    func setupSearchController() {
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.definesPresentationContext = false
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true

        let searchBar = searchController.searchBar

        view.addSubview(searchBar)

        searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        searchBar.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leadingAnchor).active = true
        searchBar.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.trailingAnchor).active = true
        searchBar.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).active = true

    }

    func presentSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        let searchBar = searchController.searchBar

        searchBar.removeFromSuperview()

        let baseView = searchController.view

        baseView.addSubview(searchBar)

        searchBar.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(baseView.leadingAnchor).active = true
        searchBar.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(baseView.trailingAnchor).active = true
        searchBar.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(searchController.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).active = true

        self.presentViewController(searchController, animated: true) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your navigation bar same throughout the application?

Comment: Yes, it is a simple app, with just the home screen. The search bar is on the home screen.

Comment: When do you call `setupSearchController` and `presentSearchController`

Comment: 'setUpSearchController' in 'viewDidLoad' and 'presentSearchController' is a 'UISearchControllerDelegate' method

Comment: How is the searchController created? And also why do you add the search bar to the view controller's view?

Comment: Programmatically by initialing it with a search results view controller which is a simple subclass of 'UIViewcontroller'

Comment: From my experience UISearchController is very new(buggy) and is use cases are very strict(those that work). I spent(lost) a lot of time playing with it.  Either don't do the animation  or try to fake somehow the presentation : partially animate the search bar  yourself, then present the search controller with a simple fade. No easy solution anyway ..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not quite following your logic there, but all I can say is that you can implement this really easy.

### Solution

- On your **Interface Builder** create a `UIView` will be the container
  of the `searchController`'s `searchBar` and set the constraints as
  following:

[image]

- Connect that `UIView` to the `UIViewController` and name it searchBarContainer
- Create a property of `UISearchController` that you want to use: `var searchController: UISearchController! = nil`
- Add **searchController.searchBar** into the **searchBarContainer**

Luckily your controller should look like this: (*Note that here I have not implemented the delegates here but you can take care of that as this is not related to the animation :)*)

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController {
    var searchController: UISearchController! = nil
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBarContainer: UIView!

    // MARK: - View Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        self.searchBarContainer.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Setup the frame each time that the view appears in order to fit the width of the screen
        // If you use autolayout just call searchController.searchBar.layoutIfNeeded()
        var frame = searchController.searchBar.bounds
        frame.size.width = self.view.bounds.size.width
        searchController.searchBar.frame = frame
    }
}
```

### Output

**My Solution**

[image]

**iOS Contacts**

[image]

Comment: In this case, when you tap on the search the search bar is not animated to move up. It is suddenly placed in the navigation bar area. On the simulator Debug > Slow Animations or Press Command T to see what I meant. When you cancel you will see a smooth animation but when you tap on the search bar you will not see any animation.

Comment: I want it to be animated (to move up) when tapped on the search bar.

Comment: I see no difference with the iOS contacts app, that is what you wanted right? Or do you want a customized animation which is not related to iOS Contact App, as I achieved that?

Comment: In the contacts app, there is an animation when you tap on the search bar. The search moves up. In the proposed solution, the search bar suddenly jumps (no animation) to the nav bar area. On your simulator press Command T and try your app and then try contacts app. You will be able to see the difference.

Comment: @user1046037 Please check the updated image for the output, and show me the problem, so we can fix it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105751/discussion-between-user1046037-and-eridb).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work unless the container view matches the width of the view controller. If I try to make the container smaller, the cancel button ends up hanging off the right side of the screen